# How to add email from session into a form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

Im trying to get the email from the user logged into my react app but having some trouble.

[image]

Above is my session coming from cognito

Below is where my data is being added into the form. The fetch()data is added correctly, but i need a way to add the email from cognito.

```
  componentDidMount() {
fetch("https://ezha2ns0bl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/userdata")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        firstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
        middlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
        surname: result.Item.userLastName,
        city: result.Item.userCity,
        postcode: result.Item.userPostCode,
        state: result.Item.userState,
        email: ,
        about: result.Item.userAbout,

        formfirstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
        formmiddlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
        formsurname: result.Item.userLastName,
        formcity: result.Item.userCity,
        formpostcode: result.postcode,
        formstate: result.Item.userState,
        formabout: result.Item.userAbout,
      });
    },
  )
```

This is data from fetch()

```
Item    
userLastName    "Pearson"
userMiddleName  "A"
userEmail   "testapi12@gmail.com"
userType    "jobseeker"
userAbout   "I am Jane and I'm looking for a job"
userFirstName   "Jane"
userState   "VIC"
userPostcode    "3976"
userCity    "Melbourne"
```

Now i want my email to come from the session and the rest of the information from userdata.

How would i make this happen ?

Comment: Can you add a full example (in text) of what `result` looks like to your question?

Comment: Like the outcome of result.Item.userFirstName ?

Comment: The data that comes back from your fetch.

Comment: Iv added it to my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split both calls into separate functions and then add them componentdidmount(). This is where the state update will occur.

```
  getFirstApi() {
fetch("https://ezha2ns0bl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/userdata")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        firstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
        middlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
        surname: result.Item.userLastName,
        city: result.Item.userCity,
        postcode: result.Item.userPostcode,
        state: result.Item.userState,
        about: result.Item.userAbout,

        formfirstname: result.Item.userFirstName,
        formmiddlename: result.Item.userMiddleName,
        formsurname: result.Item.userLastName,
        formcity: result.Item.userCity,
        formpostcode: result.postcode,
        formstate: result.Item.userState,
        formabout: result.Item.userAbout,
      });
    },
  )


 }

  getSecondApi() {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
      this.setState({email: user.attributes.email, formemail: user.attributes.email})
     // console.log('user email = ' + user.attributes.email):
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFirstApi();
    this.getSecondApi();

  }
```